# I want to be able to filter a field where I can do a batch.update on flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

var nycRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("FoodOrders").doc(); 
    // I want to specify a field here like where()
    // e.g var nycRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("FoodOrders").where("MyId",isEqualTo: myId);
batch.update(nycRef, {"Paid": true});
    
batch.commit();
```

But I get an error saying

> The argument type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to
> the parameter type 'DocumentReference<Object?>'.

Is there a way of filtering my batch write

I want to batch.update specifically where field MyId is equal to myId,how do I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as also described the steps by @DougStevenson .

```
final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("FoodOrders").where("MyId", isEqualTo: myId);

query.get().then((querySnapshot) {// query it 
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) { //and then iterate init
    batch.update(doc.reference, {"Paid": true});
  });
  
  batch.commit();
});
```

Comment: good to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't support updating all of the documents returned by a query like you can in SQL.  The only way to do what you want is to perform each of these in sequence:

1. Query for the documents.
2. Iterate over all the documents in the resulting snapshot.
3. For each document reference in the set, update it with new values